# function pointer as static member of a structure

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Please look at the definition of the structure below:

```
struct rectangle
{
   int len,bre;
   static int diagonal;
   static (int) (*ptr) (int,int);
};

int rectangle::diagonal;
rectangle::ptr; // (WHAT SHOULD COME HERE)

rectangle r1,r2;
```

Hi friends, I have defined a structure here. We know that the size of 'r1' or 'r2' is sum of the members 'len and 'bre' only.

Now to allocate memory for the *static members* we must do it explicitly. The allocation for the static member *diagonal* is fine.
But what should I give in the place: (WHAT SHOULD COME HERE) so that the memory allocation for the *function pointer* is fine.

Hope my explanation is clear to you. Please do help me.

Comment: what you have in the struct should be used for the decl. (and you can lose the parens around the leading `(int)`, btw).

Comment: `int (*rectangle::ptr) (int,int);`

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to typedef a function and use it there:

```
typedef int (*MyFunction) (int,int);
struct rectangle
{
    ...
    static MyFunction ptr;
};
MyFunction rectangle::ptr = /*initialize it here*/
```

But also you can do it as
    int (*rectangle::ptr)(int,int)

Answer (score 1):

Below is the correct way:

```
struct rectangle
{
...
   static int (*ptr) (int,int);
       // ^^^ no braces needed
};

int (rectangle::*ptr) (int, int);
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ defining a function pointer
```

Whenever there is a confusion related to function pointer, make a `typedef` and use it:

```
typedef int (*fptr) (int,int);
struct rectangle
{
   static fptr ptr;
};

fptr rectangle::ptr;
```

Comment: I found this answer very useful. thank you so much. but can't it be achived without using typedef?

Comment: @user655298, The first example in my answer is without `typedef`. It's just that `typedef` is preferable way of doing here.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
struct rectangle
{
   int len,bre;
   static int diagonal;
   static int (*ptr) (int,int);
};

int rectangle::diagonal;
int (*rectangle::ptr)(int,int) = NULL;

rectangle r1,r2
```

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I learnt a new thing because of you!